# How to group by uniform intervals of data between a maximum and minimum using the MongoDB aggregator?

Tags: mongodb, aggregator

Let's say I have a whole mess of data that yields a range of integer values for a particular field...  I'd like to see those ranked by a grouping of intervals of occurrence, perhaps because I am clustering...like so:

```
[{
  _id: {
    response_time: "3-4"
  },
  count: 234,
  countries: ['US', 'Canada', 'UK']
}, {
  _id: {
    response_time: "4-5"
  },
  count: 452,
  countries: ['US', 'Canada', 'UK', 'Poland']
}, ...
}]
```

How can I write a quick and dirty way to A) group the collection data by equally spaced intervals over B) a minimum and maximum range using a MongoDB aggregator?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to quickly formulate a conditional grouping syntax for MongoDB aggregators, we first adopt the pattern, per MongoDB syntax:

```
$cond: [
  { <conditional> }, // test the conditional
  <truthy_value>,  // assign if true
  $cond: [ // evaluate if false
    { <conditional> },
    <truthy_value>,
    ...  // and so forth
  ]
]
```

In order to do that muy rapidamente, without having to write every last interval out in a deeply nested conditional, we can use this handy recursive algorithm (that you import in your shell script or node.js script of course):

```
$condIntervalBuilder = function (field, interval, min, max) {
    if (min < max - 1) {
      var cond = [
        { '$and': [{ $gt:[field, min] }, { $lte: [field, min + interval] }] },
        [min, '-', (min + interval)].join('')
      ];
    if ((min + interval) > max) {
      cond.push(ag.$condIntervalBuilder(field, (max - min), min, max));
    } else {
      min += interval;
      cond.push(ag.$condIntervalBuilder(field, interval, min, max));
    }
  } else if (min >= max - 1 ) {
    var cond = [
      { $gt: [field, max] },
      [ max, '<' ].join(''), // Accounts for all outside the range
      [ min, '<' ].join('') // Lesser upper bound
    ];
  }
  return { $cond: cond };
};
```

Then, we can invoke it in-line or assign it to a variable that we use elsewhere in our analysis.